# Is there a ROBLOX player for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: games

Just a Question.
Can i play ROBLOX on Ubuntu
WITHOUT WINE ,playonlinux and Darling?
Because it wont work with Wine Playonlinux and Darling
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Roblox has no official availability on Linux, and is known to be incompatible with Wine/PlayOnLinux.

Comment: thx for the information i will play it on my other pc that runs windows